# MediaWiki Short URL 404s

Tags: nginx, mediawiki, nginx-config

Even when I've configured my settings and followed every step like I was suppose to, my page (/view/Main_Page) still 404s. I am using the latest MediaWiki on PHP 8.2.

This is my LocalSettings.php:

```
`
$wgScriptPath = "";

$wgArticlePath = "/view/$1";

$wgUsePathInfo = true;`
```

and

```
`$wgEnableUploads = true;

$wgGenerateThumbnailOnParse = false;
`
```

And then this is my sites-available/default config:

```
`server {

    server_name <website> www.<website>;

    root /var/www/html/mediawiki;

    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include fastcgi_params;

    }

    location ~ \.ht {

        deny all;

    }

    location @rewrite {

        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php;

    }

    location ^~ /maintenance/ {

        return 403;

    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<website>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<website>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {

    if ($host = www.<website>) {

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = <website>) {

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;

    listen [::]:80;

    server_name <website> www.<website>;

    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}`
```

What am I doing wrong? Doing "index.php?title=Main_Page" still works, but "view/Main_Page" 404s on the site.

I tried to google it, but nothing shows up.

Comment: The location `@rewrite` is not reacheable.

You need a rewrite rule to `/index.php?title=$1`.